# Can we use LWC components in React Application?

Tags: lightning-web-components, react

Is it possible to use LWC components in React application? We are trying to get some help on this but we don't see any supporting articles so far.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. LWC is currently open source framework available on github [here](https://github.com/salesforce/lwc) with documentation [here](https://lwc.dev/guide/introduction) and site [here](http://lwc.dev)

It can be used like any other framework, the only question here is why you want to use it together with react.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would actually use LWC within React app but you might want to check this guide describing how to use "[Lightning Design System for React](https://react.lightningdesignsystem.com/getting-started/)"